# C# Equivalent to Java's Double Brace Initialization?

Tags: c#

Expected code in C# (that Java has)

```
List<String> myList = new List<String>() {{
    add("Hello");
    add("World!");
}}
// myList = [ "Hello", "World" ]
```

Just wondering if there is an equivalent, possibly with C#'s static constructors?

**EDIT:**

To clarify this isn't explicitly for Collections but for any class structure.
For example:

```
abstract class myClass {
  String data;
  List<String> list;
  void setupList() {
    list = new List<String>();
  }
}

...

var obj = new myClass() {{
  data = "Yo";
  setupList();
}};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an object initializer that also uses collection initializers (note the type inference in the collection initializers, the List that is created is of type List) :

```
var myClass = new MyClass{
    Data = "foo",
    List = new List{"item1", "item2"},
    IntArray = new[]{1,2,3},
    Dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>{{"key1","value1"},{"key2","value2"}},
};
```

You can't call arbitrary methods like SetupList() in an initializer, instead you would initialize the List property the first time it is accessed or statically, etc.
You can use the Lazy class or implement it yourself like so (?? is the null coalescing operator):

```
class MyClass{
    public string Data { get; set; }

    private IList<string> _list0 = new List();

    public IList<string> List0
    {
        get
        {
            return _list0;
        }
    }

    private IList<string> _list1;

    public IList<string> List1
    {
        get
        {
            return _list1 ?? (_list1 = new List());
        }
    }

    private readonly Lazy<IList<string>> _lazyList = new Lazy<IList<string>>(() => new List<string>()); 

    public IList<string> List2
    {
        get
        {
             return _lazyList.Value;
        }
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 14):

You're looking for the collection initializer syntax:

```
List<String> myList = new List<String>() {"Hello","World!"};
```

Comment: And you can leave off the `()` in C#.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can add items to a list of strings

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("Hello");
myList.Add("World!");
```

And if you want to remove them you can simply do this

```
myList.Remove("Hello");
myList.Remove("World!");
```